# Comparisons of the Android framework's structure to the MFC/Win32's structure?

Tags: android, windows, frameworks

I develop for both Android and Windows (using MFC and sometimes win32) and yesterday I was casually comparing the two frameworks. They are very, very different obviously, and as a result developing for windows is ALOT different to developing for Android. I was wondering where people think frameworks like Android are superior structurally to frameworks like win32 (eg Message system vs Event Listeners). I want an idea of the general opinion on this kind on comparison.

I would like to add that I understand that these frameworks run on very different devices (obviously Windows has to deal with a lot more IO and user input because of the multiple Output devices it has to cope with and its complex window GUI), however there must be some core features which these frameworks share and that can be compared.. and if there aren't and I am being an idiot (which no doubt someone will point out) I would love to know why such a comparison is invalid :) cheers.

Another example would be Android lack of MVP structure vs Windows' MFC Doc/View.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a long while since I've touched mfc but I would have thought that you could compare the intent model to that of messaging?

With regards to MVC we've settled on achieving this via the use of a single activity as a window manager, fragments are views and controllers are straight Java classes.
I think MVP could be satisfied similarly with activities being presenters. Possibly using a broadcast receiver as a front controller.

Comment: Took a while for Google to sort things out, but once Fragments were introduced true MVC was possible.