# Create an android application like win32 SDK programming

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android programming and I wanted to create an application(vocabulary enhancer/words reminder which I already have for windows ) which pops up at certain time intervals to remind the words I saved earlier.

I thought android programming would be like programming windows which uses  visual studio 6 or the latest.

I created a simple hello world program but it involved too many XML and other file references and inclusions.

Is there a way to create applications for android like win32 SDK using which we can create applications for windows. Like createwindows and other straight forward methods instead of having something like mfc or the one android programming uses ?

Comment: Using the Win32 API to write Android apps would make little sense, because Android apps aren't Win32 apps. The way you use an Android app, the way it interacts with other apps, and the way the OS manages it differs from a desktop application. The reason why you think the Win32 API is more straight-forward is probably largely because you're more used to it than Android's APIs. The way to overcome that is to gain experience of the Android APIs by using them.

Comment: What i thought as a possibility is like .net framework has options to use win32 api... so if there could be an option in android programming like that then that could be nice... that is what my thought was. anyway ... the answers and your comment explained it.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what's "too many XML", other than a great name for a band.

If you're serious in your question, then I suggest you begin here: [Comparisons of the Android framework's structure to the MFC/Win32's structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663585/comparisons-of-the-android-frameworks-structure-to-the-mfc-win32s-structure) and work your way forward.

Otherwise, I suggest you do form that band.

Comment: Nobody has taken up your suggestion.  But there is a Korean indie band called "2 day old sneakers".   ( HTH :-) )

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to the Win32 API for Android.  The closest you will get would be to talk to the (native) Linux OS.  But that will only work if your device is rooted.

And that is the point.  Something like the Win32 API would allow an Android app to do things that can interfere with other apps ... and compromise the security of the user's device.